# FileNotFound Exception in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

(i'm new in Java) ... I want to store some class fields values in a HashMap then write it to a file (the path is passed as an argument) and then restore HashMap and fetch needed info. In my constructor called Carte,  i get an exception that file is not found , anyway it's in the right place and saved data is in my xml file. Any ideas on this point

**An exception has occured : java.io.FileNotFoundException: users/stefan/desktop/lol.xml (No such file or directory)**

```
// Salveaza toate obiectele create intr-un fisier
    public void salveazaObiecteleCreate(String caleSpreFisier) {

        HashMap table = new HashMap();

    table.put("Autorul", numelePrenumeleAutorului);
    table.put("Denumirea cartii", denumireaCartii);
    table.put ("Culoarea cartii",culoareaCartii);
    table.put ("Genul cartii ",gen);
    table.put ("Limba",limba);
    table.put ("Numarul de copii",numarulDeCopii);
    table.put ("Numarul de pagini",numarulDePagini);
    table.put ("Pretul cartii",pretulCartii);

  try  {

      File file = new File(caleSpreFisier);  
      FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);  
      ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(f);          
      s.writeObject(table);
      s.close();

       } catch(Exception e){

           System.out.println("An exception has occured");     
    }   
}


public Carte (String caleSpreFisier) {


 HashMap table = new HashMap();

File file = new File(caleSpreFisier); 


try  {

FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(file);  
ObjectInputStream s = new ObjectInputStream(f);  
table = (HashMap)s.readObject();         
s.close();

 } catch(Exception e){

           System.out.println("An exception has occured : "+e);     
    }

for (Object key: table.keySet()) {

    System.out.println(table.get(key));
}

}

// end of class

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the message:

> An exception has occured : java.io.FileNotFoundException: users/stefan/desktop/lol.xml

Note that it's `"users/stefan/[...]"` - it's a relative filename, so will be resolved relative to the current working directory. Are you sure you didn't mean `"/users/stefan/desktop/lol.xml"` with a leading slash to indicate an absolute filename?